# Eclipse and Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have had a simple Rest service running in eclipse using tomcat. Due to an unfortunate incident with GParted the setup is no more. I did however have an up-to-date backup so made a clean installation of Ubuntu, Eclipse and Java.

I then imported the project folder and added a tomcat server v7.0.
The project was accessible on: http://localhost:8080/one/api/ however with the new setup all I get is 404.

What have I forgotten ?

[image]

> java -version: java version "1.7.0_75" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   24.75-b04, mixed mode) javac -version: javac 1.7.0_75  Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)  Web Server: Tomcat v7.0 OS:
>   3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
Output of Eclipse Console:
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:one' did not find a matching property.
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 783 ms
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:25 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:25 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class api.future
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:25 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:25 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 07:21 PM'
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 18, 2015 4:50:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2667 ms


WEB.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>one</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


POM.XML
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>api</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>    
  </build>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
<version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20090211</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: did you check the permission for files

Comment: I just chown'ed workspace username:username but no luck.

Comment: open index.jsp right click on it and run it ,what the output you are getting

Comment: I had to create the index.jsp  (NEW>JSP FILE) and when I go to localhost:8080/api/    the page shows up fine.

Comment: <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: why do you have multipe welcome file with same name in your xml

Comment: I removed the one I just made. Same problem. I really am stuck for options now. There is no errors i can see it all complies and loads ok just always get a 404 page as if the URL is wrong or it just doesn’t exist. Is it possible Eclipse is not loading it onto Tomcat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71189/discussion-between-singhakash-and-devilcode).